# Стиль написания кода

Tags: java

Что бы сразу же был понятен вопрос, привожу участок кода:

```
Class crntTaskClass=null;
try {
    crntTaskClass=Class.forName(className);
    try {
        Tasks crntTask=(Tasks) crntTaskClass.newInstance();
        crntTask.run();
        System.out.print("\nPress enter to exit: ");
        try {
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).read();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Solution not found!");
}
in.close();
```

Как видно из примера, блоки try-catch имеют иерархическую структуру. Если честно, то при чтении кода, **лично мне** он кажется немного неудобным и корявым.
Возьмем тот же код и упорядочим вышеуказанные блоки по-другому:

```
Class crntTaskClass=null;
try {
    crntTaskClass=Class.forName(className);
    Tasks crntTask=(Tasks) crntTaskClass.newInstance();
    crntTask.run();
    System.out.print("\nPress enter to exit: ");
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).read();      

}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Solution not found!");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
in.close();
```

**Вопрос:** Если я буду пользоваться вторым стилем оформления блоков try-catch, то не принесет ли это мне некоторые проблемы? Например: сложности поиска "кода-виновника" при отладке или же "перекрытия" ранее объявлеными исключениями всех нижеследующих? Надеюсь на толковый ответ, который мне действительно поможет. **Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: Мне тоже интересно мнение других участников, однако отмечу, что перекрытия точно не будет - компилятор проверяет такие ситуации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разбейте всё на методы с семантикой «одна операция с try-catch» и будет вам счастье

**Update:**
Я не знаю семантику вашей задачи, но можете попробовать понять смысл подобных действий через следующий пример:

```
public void doJob(String className) {
    try {
        runTask(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Solution not found!");
    }
    in.close();
}

private void runTask(final String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    final Class crntTaskClass = Class.forName(className);
    try {
        Tasks crntTask = (Tasks) crntTaskClass.newInstance();
        crntTask.run();
        System.out.print("\nPress enter to exit: ");
        readFromReader();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readFromReader() {
    try {
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Почитайте парочку глав из книжки «Чистый Код» про методы и исключения, всё станет ясно

Comment: То есть создавать однострочные методы, в которые включать код, которые может породить исключение? Можете пожалуйста показать на примере?

Comment: update

Comment: Спасибо большое, книгу постараюсь почитать.

Answer (score 4):

Неправильная работа с исключениями. Нельзя просто так "глушить" их внутри. Кроме того, при выбросе unchecked исклюения не вызывется in.close(). Лучше так:

```
public void test() 
    throws 
        ClassNotFoundException, 
        IOException, 
        IllegalAccessException, 
        InstantiationException
{       
    try
    {
        Class crntTaskClass = Class.forName(className);
        Tasks crntTask = (Tasks) crntTaskClass.newInstance();
        crntTask.run();
        System.out.print("\nPress enter to exit: ");
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).read();      
    }
    finally
    {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

а снаружи что-то вроде:

```
try
{
    test();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logError(e);
}
```

Comment: Почему глушить нельзя? :) Зависит от задачи и контекста, где-то можем обработать исключение на месте, где-то надо пробрасывать вверх.

Comment: Обработка "на месте" обязательна для InterruptedException, это вообще очень тонкая вещь. Остальные же исключения нужно обрабатывать там, где ты знаешь, что с ними делать. В данном конкретном случае необходимо тупо выполнять последовательность команд Class.forName(), .newInstance(), .run() и т.д. не зацикливаясь на возможных ошибках, как будто их нет. И только в внешнем коде мы знаем, что делать с этими ошибками - выдать в лог, распечатать стек и т.п.

Comment: Я просто предостерег от распространённой практики "глушить" ошибки. Лучше передайте их наружу, там - тоже наружу, и т.д., и только на самых верхних уровнях ловить их.

Одно из плохих последствий "глушения" ошибок - код после catch продолжает последовательное выполнение, хотя должен быть перепрыгнут. Более обще - неправильная работа с потоком управления.

Comment: В данном случае (да и вообще) исключения глушаться исключительно ради нежелания передавать их выше, чтобы не писать обработчики снаружи, потому что лень. Но на самом деле получается наоборот - вместо одного обработчика снаружи плодяться куча "глушилок" на каждом чихе внутри.


Ещё раз - не бойтесь передавать исключения наружу.

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения простоты чтения, лучше разделить нормальный путь выполнения программы и код обработки ошибок. См. "Чистый код" Роберта Мартина.
Для этого исключения которые можно передать на верх, передаются наверх.